# PowerShell remoting vs Host Version

Tags: powershell-remoting

I have a strange issue using remoting with Powershell.

I have a script called dothis.ps1 which does the following:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $someServer -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $credential              
$result = Invoke-Command -Session $s { param($dropLocation) C:\somScript.ps1 @PSBoundParameters } -ArgumentList $DropLocation
```

This script is executed by the `InvokeProcess` of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflows.Activities`

The issue I have is that if I print out the version of Powershell from the dothis.ps1, I have 2.0.

But if I print out the version of the Powershell from the remote script (somSecript.ps1), it gives me 1.0.

I wanted to know the version of the powershell I was running because the following command does not work: `$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions`

Can somebody explain me what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version value you're reading comes out of the registry apparently, even though you're on a newer version of PS (since PS v1 doesn't support sessions). Reading [this other StackOverflow article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/powershell-query-features-returns-wrong-result) pointed me to `$psversiontable`, which should get you exactly what you're after.

Comment: +1 right but you should post the link to the other article too.

Comment: Done, I had closed it earlier but since you mentioned it, I went and dug it up. Thanks!